# How to show loader in button only to current mapped value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have placed loader if the button is clicked the loader runs, but its mapped to get value from api so if i click one button the loader runs for all button, how to do it only for corresponding element

my loader is:

```
<button id="Addlist" onClick={() => this.onAddProvider(providerList.id)} className="btn info"> {this.state.loading ? (
      <div className="search-loader">
        <Loader
          visible={this.state.loading}
          type="Oval"
          color="#092b50"
          height={50}
          width={50}
        />
      </div>
    ) : "Add to List"}</button>
```

As the button is mapped in loop loader runs for all button if i click one button,

eg:

[image: loader image]

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `state.loading` to true when a button is clicked, I suppose. But in your Loader component you are using that one `state.loading` variable for each of the buttons and whichever button is clicked, each of the loaders receive the true value for `visible`.

A solution would be to store the id of the provider in `state.providerIdLoading` if the provider is loading and for the condition of `visible` in the Loader you could place `state.providerIdLoading === providerList.id`. When the provider is finished loading you could set the value to false or whatever is not a providerId.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your loading state to something like

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState({providerID1: false, providerID2: false, ...})
```

and your `Loader` condition will change to

```
<button id="Addlist" onClick={() => this.onAddProvider(providerList.id)} className="btn info"> {this.state.loading[providerList.id] ? (
  <div className="search-loader">
    <Loader
      visible={this.state.loading[providerList.id]}
      type="Oval"
      color="#092b50"
      height={50}
      width={50}
    />
  </div>
) : "Add to List"}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
this.state = {
  loading: ""
};

onAddProvider = id => {
  this.setState({ loading: id });
}

<button id="Addlist" onClick={() => this.onAddProvider(providerList.id)} className="btn info">
  {
    this.state.loading === providerList.id ? (
      <div className="search-loader">
        <Loader
          visible={this.state.loading === providerList.id}
          type="Oval"
          color="#092b50"
          height={50}
          width={50}
        />
      </div>
    ) : "Add to List"
  }
</button>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of having `loading` as boolean, please use loading as `id` and match with the current `id`.

Once loading is done then reset the value to empty string like

```
this.setState({ loading: "" });
```